# Get a specific text for a status(0,S) as Open / Save while Querying in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

select status from register;

```
id status
1    O
2    S
```

**I want the query to return O as Open and S as Submit.**
**I am using oracle**

This might be simple for some people here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `decode` or `case`.  I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: @sstan decode worked for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select DECODE(STATUS,'O','Open','S','Submit for Review') FROM Register;
```

This Will Do The Need Full.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Case Statement`

```
select case when status = 'O' then 'Open' 
            When status = 'S' then 'Submit'
       END as status
```